# keyboard buttons are not working at the time of changing password

Tags: boot, keyboard, password-recovery, username, gnu-screen

when i forget my admin user passwrd i use the way of recovery mode ,i got the step of changing passwrd successfully like this .........recovery mode/root/## mount -rw -o remount/ passwd /enter new passwd
but in the last step my keyboard buttons is not working 
in shortly my problem is that my keyboard buttons is not working at the time of entering new password

but after when i click on the enter button two time ,my keyboard gets normally....

Comment: In command console, it won't show anything when you typing password. Just type in mind

Answer (score 1):

When you are prompted for a password, the keys you type are hidden for privacy reasons. They are, however, still processed normally, even though you can't see them.